# html css nav list hover problems

Tags: html, css, hover

I have all li with a hover background, but is there away instead of not:lastchild like not: id1 id4 ? Cause i want some li without that hover effect.

```
nav ul li.selected, nav ul li:hover, nav ul li:focus{
    background-color: #0047B2;
}
```

Comment: Can you please also show HTML code ?

Comment: You should also consider taking some basic HTML/CSS classes, like on http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web. This is a super simple problem, and you'd be able to knock them out with SO help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the ID as a specific case.

```
nav ul li#id4 {
    background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: Would you have to declare that after the rule above to ensure it overrides it?

Comment: not necessarily. the ID should overrule a class or element style

Answer (score 0):

you have to give all elements you want to have a hover effect a class and just specify this class in the css file.